# Writing/reading data while rebuilding RAID array

Tags: hard-drive, debian, raid, software-raid

I understand its best to limit disk activity as much as possible during a RAID rebuild/resync to reduce the risk of data loss and to prevent slowing down the rebuild process by adding more activity.

I configured my server for RAID 10. If I continue to write new data during rebuild - is this new data written to all the disks in RAID or just one?

Answer (score 0):

You can safely write data to an array which is being rebuild. it will be stored on the array, which [eventually] will be all the disks.

However any activity will slow down the rebuild.

Comment: I understand, but does the initial sync need to complete before the new data is written across the disks? Or will new data be put on one disk and once the sync is complete it'll write across them?